# How to create output object for Xamarin.TensorFlow.Lite Interpreter.RunForMultipleInputsOutputs() when model is objection detection type

Tags: xamarin.forms, tensorflow-lite

I am stuck trying to figure out the magic Object for working with Xamarin.TensorFlow.Lite Interpreter.RunForMultipleInputsOutputs().

My object detection model outputs the following (exported from Azure Custom Vision)

> - detected_boxes The detected bounding boxes. Each bounding box is represented as [x1, y1, x2, y2] >where (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) are the coordinates of box corners.
> - detected_scores Probability for each detected boxes.
> - detected_classes The class index for the detected boxes.

I know it needs to fit something like how the [tensorflow lite docs describe](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/object_detection/overview#output_signature) the output (except the number of detections):

[image: tensorflowlite outputs]

Most of the examples I have found only work with image classification models which only have 1 output: [blog1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/android-apps-tensorflow/) [blog2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/image-classification-xamarin-android/) However I did find an Issue that is that exact same issue I am having: https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/issues/565

I tried following the [tensorflow api](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/java/org/tensorflow/lite/Interpreter#parameters_15), and the [example code of the GitHub issue](https://github.com/h-maac/Xamarin.Android.TensorFlow.Lite/blob/master/TFLDemo/ObjectDetection/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.cs)(appreciated the sharing of that), but still crashing in the oblivion (Object not set to instance of object).

```cs
            int detectedBoxesOutputIndex = Interpreter.GetOutputIndex("detected_boxes"); // 0
            int detectedClassesOutputIndex = Interpreter.GetOutputIndex("detected_classes"); // 1
            int detectedScoresOutputIndex = Interpreter.GetOutputIndex("detected_scores"); // 2

            int numDetections = Interpreter
                .GetOutputTensor(detectedClassesOutputIndex)
                .NumElements();

            var outputDict = new Dictionary<Java.Lang.Integer, Java.Lang.Object>();

            int batchSize = 1;
            // new float [][][]
            _OutputBoxes = CreateJaggedArray(batchSize, numDetections, 4);
            _OutputClasses = CreateJaggedArray(batchSize, numDetections);
            _OutputScores = CreateJaggedArray(batchSize, numDetections);

            var mOutputBoxes = OutputBoxes;
            var mOutputClasses = OutputClasses;
            var mOutputScores = OutputScores;

            Java.Lang.Object[] inputArray = { imageByteBuffer };

            var outputMap = new Dictionary<Java.Lang.Integer, Java.Lang.Object>();
            outputMap.Add(new Java.Lang.Integer(detectedBoxesOutputIndex), mOutputBoxes);
            outputMap.Add(new Java.Lang.Integer(detectedClassesOutputIndex), mOutputClasses);
            outputMap.Add(new Java.Lang.Integer(detectedScoresOutputIndex), mOutputScores);

            //stuck here
            Interpreter.RunForMultipleInputsOutputs(inputArray, outputMap);
```

I can get the output of the first tensor via `Interpreter.Run(img,output)` where output is a float[64][4], so I know the model and all the image byte buffer prep is done correctly.

My Xamarin Forms Project: https://github.com/twofingerrightclick/GardenDefenseSystem/blob/master/GardenDefenseSystem/GardenDefenseSystem.Android/TensorflowObjectDetector.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an Issue on github, and solved the problem there in detail : https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/668